# Matlab estimateAssetMoments example error

Tags: matlab, timetable

When I use the matlab example (https://uk.mathworks.com/help/finance/asset-returns-and-moments-of-asset-returns-using-portfolio-object.html):

```
m = [ 0.05; 0.1; 0.12; 0.18 ];
C = [ 0.0064 0.00408 0.00192 0; 
      0.00408 0.0289 0.0204 0.0119;
      0.00192 0.0204 0.0576 0.0336;
      0 0.0119 0.0336 0.1225 ];
m = m/12;
C = C/12;

assetRetnScenarios = portsim(m', C, 120);

dates = datetime(datenum(2001,1:120,31), 'ConvertFrom', 'datenum');

assetsName = {'Bonds', 'LargeCap', 'SmallCap', 'Emerging'};

assetRetnTimeTable = array2timetable(assetRetnScenarios,'RowTimes',dates,'VariableNames', assetsName); 

q = Portfolio;

q = estimateAssetMoments(q, assetRetnTimeTable);
```

I get the following error:

> Error using Portfolio/estimateAssetMoments (line 100) AssetReturns
>   must be a matrix with either finite or NaN values.

But I am unable to figure out why. Running 2017b with financial toolbox installed.

Comment: Which exact demo from that page are you running?

Comment: When I go to your linked documentation, I can not find EXACTLY your code. You have not shared a matlab example, right? You shared a modification of one. What if you do not add the dates?

Comment: All the necessary elements required to illustrate the problem are exactly as in the matlab example. The Code is under this section (correction): Estimating Asset Moments from Time Series Data

Comment: Running the actual demo also gives me an error in 2017a, but not in 2018b. The documentation is for 2018b.